Can someone file a patent for your invention in another country while your application with the USPTO is in provisional state?

Inventor files provisional application with USPTO, obtains "patent pending" status.
Inventor then discloses his inventor to potential investors.

Can these potential investors, or anyone, steal the inventor's invention and file a patent for it in another country?

Practically speaking I don't think this is likely to happen. Before disclosing to an investor you would execute a non-disclosure agreement which would prove you communicated to them. Assuming you file your non-provisional application promptly it will almost assuredly publish before any foreign filings could be granted. You would sue them if they tried to steal your invention and you would have a great case considering the earlier priority and signed NDAs. Venture capital firms would destroy their reputation and probably their business if they tried stealing an invention. Who would ever work with them afterwards?

VCs and investors in general are known to be reluctant to sign NDAs. In doesn't make sense for them. Given the volume of pitches they get, they would be exposing themselves to too much liability.

I still believe VCs are unlikely to steal your invention.


Can these potential investors, or anyone, steal the inventor's invention and file a patent for it in another country?

Legally, no. In most countries, only the inventor (or their assignee) may patent an invention. In the U.S., for example, an oath or declaration is a required part of the process.
Of course, not much actually stops a dishonest person from falsely claiming to have invented something they in fact learned from somewhere, and obtaining a patent on it. While this is illegal conduct, it is hard to prove.
To lessen the possibility of this, one can always publish a document describing the invention earlier than the normal publication of patent applications (but after filing the provisional). Such a document can count as prior art against an imitator filing in a foreign country. Certain requirements must be met to ensure it will count as prior art. Of course, this approach has risks too in that early disclosure allows others to patent (or destroy novelty of) related ideas before you have a chance to make additional filings.

But when the original provisional application is finally granted a patent, can this patent with its priority date be used to invalid the stolen patent in the international country?

Not in the general case, because the foreign country will typically not automatically count the unpublished U.S. patent application as prior art as of its filing/priority date. In the specific case in which you also file in that country with a valid priority claim, I don't know the answer.

@BearBileFarmingisTorture Your non provisional application will publish 18 months after it’s filed and that will very likely predate any foreign filings getting granted. A good reason to file the non provisional application promptly.

@bhuff36 - assuming a non provisional is filed and published, the provisional is prior art in the EPO, for rxamplr1p

@GeorgeWhite That makes sense - I assume one must file in Europe as well though for that to happen and (for one thing) it wasn't clear whether OP was planning to do so.

@GeorgeWhite Yes, but my understanding is that only works if OP files a non-provisional in EPO. Simply filing a US non-provisional that gets published wouldn't work as it is foreign wrt to EPO and doesn't get the date of the provisional but rather only the publication date when it was made public, which may not be far back enough to stop the steal.

@bhuff36 - I looked it up and you are correct. The exception to the publication or disclosure date  determining when something becomes prior art in the EPO is that EPO application become prior art for novelty only purposes at the time of filing. From Article 54 “ (3) Additionally, the content of European patent applications as filed, the dates of filing of which are prior to the date referred to in paragraph 2 and which were published on or after that date, shall be considered as comprised in the state of the art.”
